# How to access internal components on HP Envy TPC-W051MT desktop?

Tags: ssd, desktop, hp, replacement

Despite 15 years experience in computer maintenance, **I cannot figure out how to fully access the motherboard of the HP Envy Desktop TPC-W051-MT** (HP model 795-0805nz), for replacement of the NVMe SSD. The enclosure only opens on one side, and the chassis is very monolithic.

It appears to me that the first thing to do would be removing the front bezel, so that one could probably then tilt the black metal cage hat holds the SATA drives. So, I lifted up its platic hooks, orange circled on the attached picture.
But, I can only access such hooks on one side of the front bezel, and it does not let himself being removed nor even tilted.

I could not find any service manual for this desktop.

[image: HP Envy TPC-W051-MT inner metal cage]

(N.B. The silver screw visible in the middle of the black metal panel holds nothing apart from a plastic part.)

[image: HP Envy TPC-W051-MT front bezel hooks]
[image: HP Envy TPC-W051-MT oblique view]

Comment: The entire side where you've circled parts is actually a hinge. The whole drive assembly should tilt straight up as you see [here](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1623662/Hp-Envy-795.html#manual). There's a lock somewhere holding it in place.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, there was likely a lock that I couldn't find. I ended up by adding a SATA SSD drive and install the OS on it, using an Y SATA power splitter to share the unique power output with another HDD that the computer already had.

Comment: Headscratcher indeed. I guess it's still too new model for HP to release the maintenance guide...